# Why could not load sharpsvn or one of its dependencies is coming only while publishing asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am working on a asp.net website in which I am using sharpsvn assemblies for svn check-in/out related activities and have 64 bit Windows-7 Operating system. When I was trying to run the application it was giving me error message as "Could not load sharpsvn or one of its dependencies ". To handle this issue I have gone through tools-->Options-->Project and Solutions-->Web Projects--> and check the "Use the 64 bit version of IIS" and application start to work as expected.

Even the solution works fine after this setting when I am trying to publish my website by using publish option of visual studio explorer it is still giving me same error i.e.

> "Could not load sharpsvn or one of its dependencies "

so how can I resolved this issue?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15352528/181221

Comment: yes intially I tried this one only

Comment: When I am running through my solution in asp.net it is working fine only when I am trying to publish it is giving me this error

Comment: And you selected x64 in your publishing configuration?

Comment: In the build configuration I have set platform target as x64 and the configuration used is "Release" and while publishing the website also in the settings option I have used release option.

Comment: Is anything more I would have to do?

Comment: So have you checked the filesystem for the published location, have you verified that the assemblies are not present?

Comment: yes assemblies are not present in that location

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the references are set Copy Local -> True.

If they still dont appear consider adding them as Nuget packages.

Comment: Copy Local is true for all of this assemblies

Comment: Publishing itself is not getting successful so not only sharpsvn but all other assemblies of the solution is also not getting copied into published location

Comment: Are you saying that the whole Publishing process is failing? Or just that you aren not getting the dll's you expected and that causes a runtime error?

Comment: The whole publishing process is failing with the error as "Could not load file or assembly 'SharpSvn' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. ASPNETCOMPILER 
"

Comment: Well, within your OP says you cannot *run* the code, now you are saying *publish*. I would re-visit *all* of the points in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352528/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-sharpsvn-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attemp

Comment: When I am running through my solution in asp.net it is working fine only when I am trying to publish it is giving me this error

Comment: Above was my comment 5 hour back

Comment: If anywhere I have written that cannot run the code?

Comment: "When I was trying to run the application it was giving me error message"

"yes intially I tried this one only" - I dont know what you mean by that, please elaborate.